# Is it OK to pass (double ***) pointers using (void **)?

Tags: c, pointers, casting, language-lawyer, void-pointers

I compile the code below with *gcc* using `-Wall -Werror` and it compiles cleanly, runs as expected; however, I'm just curious if it is OK, in **ANSI** and/or **ISO C** context, to pass a `(double ***)` pointer via `(void **)`.

The **ISO/IEC 9899:2017**, section 6.6 - 9 says:

> "The array-subscript `[]` and member-access `.` and `->` operators,
>   the address `&` and indirection `*` unary operators, and **pointer
>   casts** may be used in the creation of an address constant, but the
>   value of an object shall not be accessed by use of these operators."

In connection to this recommendation, the function `allocateMatrix` is, in fact, supposed to *just* allocate memory and return the corresponding address; so, please disregard the inner loop that assign values, it's there for test purposes only.

```
void allocateMatrix(int n, void **a) {
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    double **pTmp = calloc(n, sizeof(double *));

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        pTmp[i] = malloc(n * sizeof(double));

        // following loop is inserted to make sure code runs as expected
        // this does not exists in real code
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            pTmp[i][j] = (double)(i + 1) + (double)(j + 1) / 10.0f;
        }
    }

    *a = pTmp;
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    int n = 5;
    double **a = NULL;

    // "a" is a (double **) pointer; so, "&a" is now a (double ***) pointer
    allocateMatrix(n, (void **)&a);

    // testing...
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf("%6.2lf", a[i][j]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Any object pointer type can be converted to/from `void*`, bit not to `void**`. And you don't even need to. Modify the function to take `void*`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C standard allows for conversion to and from `void *`, however that lattitute does **not** exist for `void **`.

Change the function argument to `void *` and cast it appropriately and it will work.

```
void allocateMatrix(int n, void *a) {
    ...
    *(double ***)a = pTmp;
}
```

And change remove the cast from the function call:

```
allocateMatrix(n, &a);
```

Comment: `C standard allows for conversion to and from void *` Doesn't this mean that any pointer can be converted to/from `void*` then the `void*` itself can be converted to/from `void**`?

Comment: No, it doesn't mean that. Why would it? `void**` is a different type which has no provisions similar to `void*`

Comment: @EugeneSh. Because `void**` is a pointer type `T*` where `typedef void *T;` so by the same rule it can be converted to/from `void*`.

Comment: @dxiv A pointer may be converted to a `void *` and back.  If you convert (for example) a `double **` to `void *`, then to `void **`, attempting to dereference the `void **` is undefined behavior.

Comment: @dbush Of course, but how is that relevant here. Point was whether a pointer can be converted to `void**` and back, and your answer appears to imply the negative.

Comment: @dxiv MAybe I misunderstood your comment. Yes, `void**` can be converted from/to `void*`. But it is not related to the original question, where you ask to convert `double ***` to `void **`. If you want to do something like `double ***` -> `void*` -> `void**` - you can't do this because you have guarantee only for conversions to `void*` and from it to *original* type.

Comment: @dxiv What I mean is that a pointer cannot be implicitly converted to `void **` and back.

Comment: @dbush The question however was about the legality of an explicit cast to `void**`. AFAICT that *is* legal as written in the original post.

Comment: @dxiv The cast is OK assuming there aren't any alignment issues.  The subsequent dereference is not.

Comment: @dbush Don't see why not. The subsequent dereference falls under the umbrella of assigning a pointer value to a `void*` variable, which is legal. Anyway, guess I'll leave this for the true language lawyers to argue farther.

Comment: @dbush: Excuse me for interrupting both of your valuable comments. Aside agreeing with one or the other, I just want to justify my understanding: From your comment "The cast is OK... The subsequent de-reference is not" what I understand is; using `void **a` in function decoration was harmless, however `*a = pTmp;` can introduce unstability, because it's de-referencing a `void **` pointer, of unknown type; is my deduction correct? (edit: yes, it is de-referencing `void **`)

Comment: @ssd Not dereferencing a `void *`, but dereferencing a `void **` which actually points to a `double ***`.  A `void *` and a `double **`, both of which are well defined types, may have different representations.